# @react-native-community/picker throws error of register two views with the same name

Tags: react-native, picker

In my React Native 0.64 app, `@react-native-community/picker 1.8.1` is used to provide dropdown options:

```
import {Picker} from "@react-native-community/picker";
return (
      ...
        <Picker
              selectedValue={country_code}
              style={{height: 50, width: 100}}
              onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                setCountryCode(itemValue)
              }>
              <Picker.Item label="UK" value="44" />
              <Picker.Item label="US" value="1" />
            </Picker>
   )
```

However it throws the error in console.oupt:

```
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNCAndroidDropdownPicker
http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.xyz_app4&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:258480:26
StaticContainer@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.xyz_app4&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:207673:17
EnsureSingleNavigator@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.xyz_app4&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:206385:24
SceneView@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.xyz_app4&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:207565:22
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
RCTView
View
CardSheet@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.xyz_app4&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:262787:23
RCTView
View
AnimatedComponent@http://10.0.2.2:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.xyz_app4&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:60266:80
```

Also here is the output on android emulator:

[image]

`picker` is a commonly used module. What causes the error here?

Comment: `@react-native-picker/picker` works without the error.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem, It happens if you are using native-base in your project.
To fix it you can use Picker from native-base by importing it as follows -

`import {Picker} from 'native-base'`